# Django summernote WYIWYG text editor is not displaying correctly with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms, summernote

In my form.py, I have the following code

```
from django import forms
import autocomplete_light
from .models import Note
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget

class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    note = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget( attrs={'width': '50%', 'height': '400px'} ), label="Description", required=False )

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        exclude = ["slug", "author"]
```

But in my template the summernote is not displaying correctly, it's only showing the toolbar.

[image]

If I then replace the SummernoteWidget to SummernoteInplaceWidget the form completely disappears. i.e.

```
note = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget( attrs={'width': '50%', 'height': '400px'} ), label="Description", required=False )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using bootstrap beside? If yes, you have to use `SummernoteInplaceWidget`.
Once, I saw a project where summernote was still including another jQuery version distinct from mine, therefore in the settings file, I noticed to include nothing.

Are you using a custom theme for your fields? Maybe this theme is applying a fixed height.